# forms/checkboxes using class to create a toggle a group from one and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm horrible with js but I'm set up to create a toggle. I can do so between two objects but not in a group... Here's what it looks like...

[image: Form with the buttons]

In my code, I created two classes, one for all, and one for the group... togglea, toggleb

```
Say '<tr><td WIDTH="50px" align="right">'
Say '<div class="roundedOne">'
Say '<input type="checkbox" name="memory" id="roundedOne" class="atoggle" />'
Say '<label for="roundedOne"></label></td>'
Say '</div>'
Say '<td width="50px">Memory</td>'

Say '<tr><td WIDTH="50px" align="right">'
Say '<div class="roundedTwo">'
Say '<input type="checkbox" name="wires" id="roundedTwo" class="atoggle" />'
Say '<label for="roundedTwo"></label></td>'
Say '</div>'
Say '<td width="50px">Wires</td></tr>'

Say '<tr><td WIDTH="50px" align="right">'
Say '<div class="roundedThree">'
Say '<input type="checkbox" name="eptest" id="roundedThree" class="atoggle" />'
Say '<label for="roundedThree"></label></td>'
Say '</div>'
Say '<td width="50px">EPTEST</td></tr>'

Say '<tr><td WIDTH="50px" align="right">'
Say '<div class="roundedFour">'
Say '<input type="checkbox" name="dcc" id="roundedFour" class="atoggle" />'
Say '<label for="roundedFour"></label></td>'
Say '</div>'
Say '<td width="50px">DCC</td></tr>'

Say '<tr><td WIDTH="50px" align="right">'
Say '<div class="roundedFive">'
Say '<input type="checkbox" name="All" id="roundedFive" class="btoggle" />'
Say '<label for="roundedFive"></label></td>'
Say '</div>'
Say '<td width="50px">All</td></tr>'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to toggle these two groups? Please ignore the say's btw, this is a small part of a much bigger cgi file written in REXX, thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.btoggle').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('.atoggle').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else{
         $('.atoggle').prop('checked', false);
    } 
});
```

This works because the click event is triggered after the checkbox has changed its status.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro I will pay it forward by helping someone today... You're an angel... William

Comment: This is what StackOverflow is about!